# Prevent FlashBuilder from building all my assets

Tags: apache-flex, assets, flash-builder

One annoying thing here..

My project contains lots of assets (a couple GB). They never change. At least not when I'm working on the main MXML code. Is there a way to prevent FlashBuilder to rebuild (delete, then copy) all my assets almost everytime I save or hit debug?

All I need to build is the main MXML file which is edited..

Thanks guys! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the unchanging assets to a separate library file. Link back to them from the 'project' 'properties'.

EDIT:
Library files can either be compile-time linked or [run-time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd1.html).

For details:
- [Flex 4.7](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ffe.html)
- [Flex 3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_7.html)

Comment: How do I move them to a separate library file?
Right now, they're all located in an assets folder in my main project.

I have not had much experience with breaking my application apart and linking stuff. But it's probably time for me to learn that :P

Comment: And will this affect all my links to the assets? (I guess the answer is yes?). And when uploading all of this to the web, how is it all handled then? =)

Comment: In FB create a new project of type 'library'. Move all of your 'assets' into it. In the 'project' 'properties' look for 'flex build path' - add the resultant .SWC from the library here.

Comment: Thanks mate. But will all my assets be contained within one .SWC file then? Which I have to compile the first time?

Comment: And how do I keep the link to the SWF file working when uploading to the web? =)

I'll read through some online. If you've got any good sites or documents for me to read regarding FlashBuilder and these kind of stuff, then please let me know :) I think I need to learn some more "advanced" stuff in regards to building librarys and using class files instead of putting all code into one big file.. =)

Comment: I'll have a look at those links. Thanks mate. =)

Comment: When I use an external Library path, do the application need to load (cache) the whole SWC file to access it's content? Or how is it connected?
What I mean is: will using an external SWC slow down my application when run from the web?

Comment: No - either its compile-time linked so its the same size as it was or it's run-time - it loads once and then is faster in the future.